# comparing values in 3 dataframes and appending missing values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 3 Dataframes .

```
Data1 -
Name_description   Numbers 
ABC                23
DEF                34
GHI                45
XYZ                43
JVK                23
LMN                21
```

Data 2 has just list of Names

```
Data 2- 
    Names            
    ABC                
    DEF                
    GHI                
    XYZ                
    JVK                
    LMN    
    PQR
    KJL
```

Data 3 again has Names and numbers

```
Data 3
Name_desc           Numbers 
    ABC                56
    DEF                67
    GHI                89
    XYZ                60
    JVK                88
    LMN                65
    PQR                100
    KJL                85
```

I want to do following things -

```
Look for all names from data 2 are present in data 1
If any names are missing then 
{
get those names
get the numbers for those missing names from data 3
append above two things (missing names & numbers) to data 1
}
else
{data1<-data1
}
```

I was just thinking to merge files but i also need to make sure that if no name is missing in data 1 from data 2 then data 1 should remain as it is. (same thing mentioned in above code)

In above case my final output should be

```
Data 1- 

Name_description   Numbers 
    ABC                23
    DEF                34
    GHI                45
    XYZ                43
    JVK                23
    LMN                21
    PQR                100
    KJL                85
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, merge `Data1` and `Data2`, then locate `NA`'s in this new data.frame and match them with `Data3`, finally, replace them with `Data3` values.

```
> tmp <- merge(Data1, Data2, by.x="Name_description", by.y="Names", all=TRUE)
> ind <- match(tmp$Name_description[is.na(tmp$Numbers)], Data3$Name_desc)
> tmp$Numbers[ind] <- Data3$Numbers[ind]
> tmp
  Name_description Numbers
1              ABC      23
2              DEF      34
3              GHI      45
4              JVK      23
5              LMN      21
6              XYZ      43
7              KJL     100
8              PQR      85
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried with Merge & it went well but wanted to see if no values are missing then how it can be handled ? thats why I was looking for something like ifelse .

Comment: @Earthshaker that is handled in `match(tmp$Name_description[is.na(tmp$Numbers)], Data3$Name_desc)` part.

Answer (score 1):

I find `dplyr::coalesce` very handy in situations like mentioned by `OP`. After joining 3 data frames 2 `Numbers` column will be available (one containing `NA`) which can be merged using `coalesce` as:

```
library(dplyr)

Data1 %>% full_join(Data2, by=c("Name_description" = "Names")) %>%
  inner_join(Data3, by=c("Name_description" = "Name_desc")) %>%
  mutate(Numbers = coalesce( Numbers.x, Numbers.y)) %>%
  select(Name_description, Numbers)

#    Name_description Numbers
# 1              ABC      23
# 2              DEF      34
# 3              GHI      45
# 4              XYZ      43
# 5              JVK      23
# 6              LMN      21
# 7              PQR     100
# 8              KJL      85
```

**Data:**

```
Data1 <- read.table(text = 
"Name_description   Numbers 
ABC                23
DEF                34
GHI                45
XYZ                43
JVK                23
LMN                21",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Data2 <- read.table(text = 
"Names            
ABC                
DEF                
GHI                
XYZ                
JVK                
LMN    
PQR
KJL",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


Data3 <- read.table(text = 
"Name_desc           Numbers 
ABC                56
DEF                67
GHI                89
XYZ                60
JVK                88
LMN                65
PQR                100
KJL                85",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr, it should look something like :

```
data1 %>% 
    bind_rows(
        data2 %>% 
        anti_join(data1) %>% 
        left_join(data3)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this in `dplyr` with `left_join` and `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)

Data4 <- Data2 %>%
  left_join(Data1, by = c("Names" = "Name_description")) %>%
  left_join(Data3, by = c("Names" = "Name_desc")) %>%
  mutate(Numbers = ifelse(is.na(Numbers.x), Numbers.y, Numbers.x)) %>%
  select(Names, Numbers)
Data4
#    Names Numbers
# 1   ABC      23
# 2   DEF      34
# 3   GHI      45
# 4   XYZ      43
# 5   JVK      23
# 6   LMN      21
# 7   PQR     100
# 8   KJL      85
```

**DATA**

```
Data1 <- read.table(text = "Name_description   Numbers 
ABC                23
DEF                34
GHI                45
XYZ                43
JVK                23
LMN                21",
                    header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Data2 <- read.table(text = "Names            
    ABC                
    DEF                
    GHI                
    XYZ                
    JVK                
    LMN    
    PQR
    KJL",
                    header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Data3 <- read.table(text = "Name_desc           Numbers 
    ABC                56
    DEF                67
    GHI                89
    XYZ                60
    JVK                88
    LMN                65
    PQR                100
    KJL                85",
                    header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We actually don't need to `merge` at all, what you want is to take the first available choice for `Number`, starting from `Data1` then `Data3`, and I suppose return NA when `Name` is in `Data2` and not in others.

The fastest way to do this is with `data.table`, but I'll give other options as well.

**data.table**

`data.table::rbindlist` doesn't use names by default (`use.names=FALSE`) so it's very convenient in this case.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(Data1,Data3,Data2))[,.SD[1,],by="Name_description"]

# 1:              ABC      23
# 2:              DEF      34
# 3:              GHI      45
# 4:              XYZ      43
# 5:              JVK      23
# 6:              LMN      21
# 7:              PQR     100
# 8:              KJL      85
```

**tidyverse solution**

the `.keep_all` argument of `dplyr::distinct` is useful to avoid a less readable use of `%>% filter(!duplicated(Names))` or `%>% group_by(Names) %>% Slice(1)`.

```
library(tidyverse)
lst(Data1,Data3,cbind(Data2,NA)) %>%
  map(setNames,c("Names","Numbers")) %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  distinct(Names,.keep_all = TRUE) 

# Names Numbers
# 1   ABC      23
# 2   DEF      34
# 3   GHI      45
# 4   XYZ      43
# 5   JVK      23
# 6   LMN      21
# 7   PQR     100
# 8   KJL      85
```

**base solution**

```
x <- do.call(rbind,lapply(list(Data1,Data3,cbind(Data2,NA)),setNames,c("Names","Numbers")))
x[!duplicated(x[[1]]),]  
#    Names Numbers
# 1    ABC      23
# 2    DEF      34
# 3    GHI      45
# 4    XYZ      43
# 5    JVK      23
# 6    LMN      21
# 13   PQR     100
# 14   KJL      85
```